# How can I use multi properties in one field using EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, editorfor

I have a `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use `Name` and `Surname` together in **one field** using `Html.EditoFor` ?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.Name + Surename???? , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Why did you want to do that?

Comment: MVC Templates are designed for use with TYPE (not value).  All views/templates can take a *Model* which is *Type*.  `model.Customer.Name + Surename` is not a resolv-able Type.  Why not create a `Customer.cshtml` template?

Comment: Ok . I understand my mistake. If I want edit this field, then I have problem. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `NameWithSurname` property to connected `Name`and `Surname` value.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    private string _NameWithSurname;

    public string NameWithSurname
    {
        get
        {
            _NameWithSurname = Name + Surname;
            return _NameWithSurname;
        }
        set {
            _NameWithSurname = value;
        }
    }
}
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.NameWithSurname  , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**NOTE**

Your  `Surname` property might be `public`, otherwise it only can use in `Customer` class.

Comment: So then once the full name is edited, which properties do you read - the first and last name or the full name?

Answer (score 1):

You should either have the name split or combined - don't try to do both.

Suppose you *do* have a "full name" textbox, the value gets edited, and the user types `Billy Bob Thornton`. How then will it know how to split back into the first and last name fields?

You need to either use separate text boxes and properties, or use a single "name" property and a single textbox.

It's fine to combine the names when *displaying* data, but when editing it's more trouble than it's worth.